# I am unable to locate wine in Raring

Tags: installation, wine

- I have added repo,
- added sources,
- restarted,
- reinstalled Ubuntu. 
  I have entered just about every useful command in the book, but when I type `apt-get install wine`, I still get the message saying **wine is unavailable**, but is referred to by another packages, no installation candidate.

I don't understand, what do I need to do?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update`? It would be better if you say exactly what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.4 the wine package is only built on x86 based architectures. You cannot run x86 Windows programs on ARM without emulating the x86 instruction set as well. You would need to run an x86 version of Ubuntu inside a chroot under `qemu` for example, to be able to run any x86 Windows programs on your ARM system.